# xPages REST service to feed a Notes Calendar Store

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I am trying to use RESTservice to get data from a resource reservation DB and provide a calendar with filter capability by resource name.
All run fine while I use the rest service without filter

```
<xe:restService id="restService2" pathInfo="/inoteslegacyjson">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewJsonLegacyService count="30000"
            databaseName="${compositeData.databaseName}"
            viewName="${compositeData.viewName}" defaultColumns="false"
            var="entry" contentType="text/plain" compact="false">
            <xp:this.columns>
                <!-- Cal Date -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$134"
                    columnName="StartDateTime">
                </xe:restViewColumn>
                <!-- Icon -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$149" columnName="$149"></xe:restViewColumn>
                <!-- Start Date -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$144"
                    columnName="StartDateTime">
                </xe:restViewColumn>
                ...
```

But when I put a search syntax like this:

```
<xe:this.search><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var isResourceFiltered:Boolean;
var strTmp:String=viewScope.resourceName;
isResourceFiltered=(strTmp.compareToIgnoreCase("All")!=0);
print ("Is result filtered:" + isResourceFiltered + ", filter: "+ strTmp);

if (!isResourceFiltered) {
    return "";
}

return "ResourceName=" + viewScope.resourceName}]]></xe:this.search>
```

I cannot see any message in console about Print() and get some errors in page:

calendarDataStore: RequestError: Unable to load /admin/resource.nsf/ResourceCalendarFiltered.xsp/inoteslegacyjson status: 500

or error 400

How does can I filter a calendar view for resource name 
(And how make a time slice to get only time period showed in the UI to avoid count="30000"?)

Comment: Confirm that viewScope.resourceName is not null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewScope.resourceName` may not be set early enough for it to be used. This could explain the lack of a print statement and the error 500 returned by the calendarDataStore.

Try adding some error handling to verify it's an issue with the component vs an error with your code.

XPages OpenLog Logger (or the corresponding code in OpenNTF Domino API) will catch uncaught exceptions and so would verify coding issues without needing try/catch blocks.

Comment: Yes seems too early, it is ==null. Thank you.
What is the way to have a filter in the right time?

Comment: `beforePageLoad` event can be used to default the `viewScope` setting. Alternatively, use `sessionScope` instead (setting a default on app start or handling null) and reload the XPage if the user is allowed to amend it on that XPage.

Comment: Got the 400 error! Using a rest plugin in browser I got this response:
{"code": 400,
"message": "Database is not full text indexed.",...}
How can I trap this to show it on the web page? I have not any code to put try-catch into.

Comment: On option would be to verify the database is FT indexed in your database initialisation / page initialisation code and redirect accordingly

Comment: It would be very useful to trap any type of error to show the whole text and trap any exception.

Comment: Fortunately I already implemented and open-sourced functionality to trap any exception in SSJS some years ago, see https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger. If you use OpenNTF Domino API, it also comes as standard in that. You just need an instance of OpenLog (separate project) installed and a custom error page in your application - the errors get caught during the XPage lifecycle and XPages code logs it out, so errors need to result in an XPage being processed to the browser. Although the error is in a REST service, I think it should still work.

Answer (score 1):

I did a Java Rest service and used FT Search to search between two date ranges. You could also work your search by resource name into that FT Search as well. In my case I did not use a view but did the lookup in Java and built the returned text in my code (to work with FullCalendar, a web based calendar). Works great and is fast.